# Where to add this information to MySQL table once user submits form

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Im new to SQL and MyPHPAdmin. I am currently really confused. I would like some advice or help please.

I am currently using Wordpress. Lets say that there are two different tables. One is "company" with columns of: user_id (with the current logged in user id), company_id, company_name and branch_id with the other table as "company_location" with columns: branch_id, branch_location. We will be manually adding the fields of location and the branch_id inside the table "company_location".

There is a form for business owners to submit a listing of their company. Once they fill out the form, all the info will be added to the company table. In the form there will be a branch location field. If they type in the branch location field and they submit the info, what kind of data should we be adding to the "company" table? Would we add the "branch_name" column with empty fields and update it once the user submits? Because we cannot link two different tables with names right it has to be with numbers (like ids)?

The reason im confused is because once we join the "company_location" and the "company" table, how can we know that this specific user has this company with this branch?

Comment: There are two tables company and company_location. company table records will we created when submitting a form by the user. company_location table records will be manually added by the system admin. you want to know how to handle a situation when there is no related record available in company_location at the time of submitting a from.  Am I correct? or correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes that is correct. How can we handle this or how can we make the two tables relatable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change logic to one of the following options.

Option 1 - user can only select locations from your **company_location** table. A drop down will help you with that. User will contact the admin in case when a location is not available and admin will insert it manually. You can store the **branch_id** in **company** table to make the relationship.

Option 2 - Remove the manual part from the admin. User can select already available location or create a new location. If user creates a new location then first save the location and create a **branch_id** key and use the newly created key in **company** table.

personally I prefer option two.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Users cannot select locations from your company_location table. This is because we want the manager or the business owner to register first by typing in the company name and the branch location. After they have created the listing, we want the employees to select the branch they are at when they sign up. So in the registration fields, we want the company name and branch to show up. Thanks @rosh-dev

Comment: Would that be Option 2? Just double-checking. @rosh-dev

Comment: So as you said in Option2. Lets say the user creates a new location and we save that location and we create a branch_id key. Would creating the same branch_id key in the company table relate to the location table? Because since we have two different tables, company and location, once the user creates a listing, the company name and the location would be inserted into different tables.

Comment: usually when we want to create a relationship between two table, first we insert record to the main table (eg company_location) and create an id (eg branch_id). Then we use that id in the detail table (eg company). So to create a relationship, we need a record in the master table before we insert record in to detail table even it is a manual (option 1) or an automated (option 2) process.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rosh-dev. I understand now. So if we were to create a relationship inserting both company and location (also doesnt matter which one inserts first) in each table wouldn't matter unless I have record living in the master table i'm guessing?

Comment: you should have a record in master or insert a record to master and use that id in your detail table. Order matters
https://www.rndblog.com/insert-into-multiple-mysql-tables-linked-by-a-foreign-key/